# c# API client using Desktop application

Tags: c#, api, rest, desktop-application

I have to create a client application to connect to an API to post and get information,
the information that I got from the company who have the API is:

```
API details for: xxxxx 
Integration: yyyyxxxx 
API URL: https://api.xyz.us/v123/ 
APP KEY: xxxxx12312xxxxx2123123xxxxx 
SECRET KEY: 11111111111111111xxxxxxxxxxx
```

I want to use c#  or other language to create the client,  I couldn't find any c# sample for desktop application, I found a  c# console basic sample,  It's like no one use APIs with c#,

Is there any sample for a client to connect to an API using C# Desktop application?

or what can I use to accomplish this task?

Thanks

Comment: Look for HttpClient, it's .NET's, well, HTTP client.

Comment: There is no difference on how you would do it from a console or desktop application. You can use the same example.

Comment: Thanks, for the quick response, any sample where is use the API key and secret key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's `HttpClient` example based on the snippet from OP's answer

```csharp
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
```

```csharp
public class RESTClient
{
    private readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    public RESTClient(string baseAddress)
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);
    }

    public void SetAuthHeader(string parameter)
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", parameter);
    }

    public async Task<string> MakeRequestAsync(HttpMethod method, string path, string postContent = "")
    {
        try
        {
            using (HttpContent content = new StringContent(postContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))
            using (HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, path))
            {
                if (method == HttpMethod.Post || method == HttpMethod.Put) request.Content = content;
                using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).ConfigureAwait(false))
                {
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                    return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "{\"errorMessages\":[\"" + ex.Message + "\"],\"errors\":{}}";
        }
    }
}
```

Usage example (WinForms)

```csharp
private RESTClient restClient;
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    restClient = new RESTClient("https://myapi.url/api");
    restClient.SetAuthHeader("iODA0NjMxMTgwMWUzYWFkYTk4NjM2MjcyOTk3MDowYTU0N2I2NzliNWRkMjliN2I4NTFlMDBkY2Y2NjQzNzQ5OTIxYzZl");
}

private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // GET
    string getJsonResult = await restClient.MakeRequestAsync(HttpMethod.Get, "path/to/method");

    // POST
    string postJsonResult = await restClient.MakeRequestAsync(HttpMethod.Post, "path/to/method", "{\"data\": \"Some Request Data\"}");


    // process data here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone who help.  I found the answer on Postman,
first I found a C# desktop client application sample.
the problem with this sample is that it didn't use an API key and secret key.
I found many answers on how to add the API key and secret key

but the one worked was the one on Postman, in the section 'code'

request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic ZmRiODA0NjMxMTgwMWUzYWFkYTk4NjM2MjcyOTk3MDowYTU0N2I2NzliNWRkMjliN2I4NTFlMDBkY2Y2NjQzNzQ5OTIxYzZl";

the complete c# code is:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

namespace restClient_0
{

    public enum httpVerb
    {
        GET,
        POST,
        PUT,
        DELETE
    }

    class RESTClient
    {
        public string endPoint { get; set; }
        public httpVerb httpMethod { get; set; }

        public RESTClient()
        {
            endPoint = "";
            httpMethod = httpVerb.GET;
        }

        public string makeRequest()
        {

            string strResponseValue = string.Empty;

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(endPoint);

            request.Method = httpMethod.ToString();
            request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic iODA0NjMxMTgwMWUzYWFkYTk4NjM2MjcyOTk3MDowYTU0N2I2NzliNWRkMjliN2I4NTFlMDBkY2Y2NjQzNzQ5OTIxYzZl";

            HttpWebResponse response = null;

            try
            {
                response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();


                //Proecess the resppnse stream... (could be JSON, XML or HTML etc..._

                using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    if (responseStream != null)
                    {
                        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                        {
                            strResponseValue = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                strResponseValue = "{\"errorMessages\":[\"" + ex.Message.ToString() + "\"],\"errors\":{}}";
            }
            finally
            {
                if (response != null)
                {
                    ((IDisposable)response).Dispose();
                }
            }

            return strResponseValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What would be the difference between HttpWebRequest   vs HttpClient ??

Comment: `HttpClient` is faster in .NET Core and has native `async` API. And it's cross-platform class. `HttpWebRequest` is deprecated class and [not recommended](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) by Microsoft for the new development.

Comment: thanks, can you write httpclient for GET and POST? ,   the current code is working for GET,  but I haven't done for POST   yet.  let me know.

Comment: What kind of Data do you want to POST? `x-form-url-encoded` or json string or what? What kind of Desktop app, WinForms?

Comment: json string, desktop WinForms.  using httpClient,